# Nodejs execute exported function from string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to know if it's possible to run a function that is named a string in nodejs. All this code is running on the server side with no browser appearance at all.

**Assuming I export a file `test.js` with the following code**

```
module.exports.test = function(x)
{
   console.log(x*5);
}
```

**Can I do this somehow?**

**main.js**

```
imp = require('test.js');
toExecute = "test";

// somehow call imp.test using toExecute`
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure:

```
imp[toExecute](5);
```

Logs `25`.

Comment: np :). just remember, objects in javascript can be indexed with bare-word style or with `[]` style. So `module.exports.test` is the same as `module.exports['test']`.